# How can I combine methods with different arguments?

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

I have four main methods:

```
+ (NSArray *)findAll;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithOrder:(NSArray *)order;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithConditions:(NSDictionary *)conditions;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithLimit:(NSRange)limit;
```

In addition, I want to combine these methods (so I can `find all` by both order and conditions, for example). Currently I'm doing (all possibilities even with arguments in a different order not shown here):

```
+ (NSArray *)findAll;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithOrder:(NSArray *)order;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithConditions:(NSDictionary *)conditions;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithLimit:(NSRange)limit;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithOrder:(NSArray *)order conditions:(NSDictionary *)conditions;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithOrder:(NSArray *)order limit:(NSRange)limit;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithConditions:(NSDictionary *)conditions limit:(NSRange)limit;
+ (NSArray *)findAllWithOrder:(NSArray *)order conditions:(NSDictionary *)conditions limit:(NSRange)limit;
```

But is there a simpler way than creating dozens of methods for this? That would be very nice. Thanks.

Comment: Yes -- don't do that.  It isn't the standard pattern across the frameworks and for good reason.  It proves to be a complete pain in the ass to maintain all those variants. Changes tend to be sweeping and you'll need to test every variant of every one.  Much better to have a small number of comprehensive methods.

Comment: See NSFetchRequest.  It isn't even clear if you need a new class or wouldn't be better off with a subclass of NSFetchRequest.  Given complexity of inputs, you'd be far better off with, say, a `Finder` class whose instances can be configured as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, that's the way you do it. I'm sure someone could find ways to get around creating dozens of similar methods, but they are very rarely used. It's pretty common for Obj-C (esp. Cocoa) objects to have large numbers of methods that differ from each other only slightly.

Comment: :( Okay, that'll be a large source code and even larger documentation then :')

Comment: I've done it and I have over 50 methods now. Thanks =D. Thanks to Copy & Paste.

Answer (score 3):

Go with the one that has all the arguments (`findAllWithOrder:conditions:limit:`) and use nil to identify unused arguments (or, in case of NSRange, `{ NSNotFound, 0 }`)

Comment: Actually I am writing a framework, and to it's users it needs to be clean and clear and of course easy to use. Your idea will work, but it doesn't fit into my and my framework's user's coding style. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, Apple uses this solution. The usually add the most used convenience methods with less args. See `NSNotificationCenter`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The way Apple accomplishes this is, in my opinion, one of the best ways to do it in Obj-C:

Define a catch-all method that takes an `options` dictionary or bitmask, and then have logic inside the method that based on the dictionary or bitmask, would execute the appropriate code.

Comment: Could you give an example or a (link to a) tutorial?

Comment: good answer, I don't like this method, though. It's never obvious what the appropriate objects/keys are for options dictionaries. Long method names are self-documenting, options dictionaries aren't.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like a candidate for Builder design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

You create i.e. Finder class with methods:

`-(void)searchOrder:(NSArray *)order;`

`-(void)searchCondition(NSDictionary *)conditions;`

and so on... These methods sets object's members to values you pass in these methods.

These methods are optional, so you can call (on object of Finder class) none of them (final effect like `+ (NSArray *)findAll;` in your situation) or some of them.

In the end you call on Finder's object method i.e. `-(NSArray *)find;` and you have results.